# Arithmetic operator in jsRender Template

Tags: javascript, jsrender

Is there any other way to perform the arithmetic operation (multiplication) with in the JSRender Template

{{:Level}} * 12

Answer (score 1):

I have achieve this requirement by using code snippet like below.

{{:Level*12}}

Comment: Correct - you can do that.